# Formatting tables to fit inside the page

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I am trying to make a table like this but it doesn't come out good as the rows overlap like this: [image]
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\input{head}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Results of the regression model} 
\label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabular}{ C{1.25in} C{.85in} *4{C{.75in}}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Parameters & \bf IV C & \bf Standard error (SE)& \bf 2SLS & \bf Standard error (SE) & \bf 2SLS & \bf Standard error (SE) &\bf GMM & \bf Standard error (SE)\\\bottomrule[1.25pt]
Cons & $2.266$ & $1.000$ & $4.087$ & $0.158$ & $4.094$ & $0.223$\\
\midrule
Educ & $0.223$ & $0.058$ & $0.118$ & $0.009$ & $0.117$ & $0.013$\\
\midrule
Exper & $0.151$ & $0.027$ & $0.105$ & $0.007$ & $0.105$ & $0.010$\\
\midrule
$\text{Exper}^2$ & $-0.003$ & $0.001$ & $-0.003$ & $0.000$ & $-0.003$ & $0.000$\\
\midrule
$South$ & $-0.086$ & $0.029$ & $-0.123$ & $0.013$ & $-0.123$ & $0.018$\\
\midrule
$Black$ & $-0.036$ & $0.056$ & $-0.127$ & $0.019$ & $-0.129$ & $0.026$\\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}\par
\bigskip
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem, please?

Comment: Your data has 7 columns but you declared 6 columns: `C{1.25in} C{.85in} *4{C{.75in}}`.

Comment: Ah I see. Fixed it :). Thank you!

Comment: Could you post a compilable code, not just a snippet? We don"t even know your document class.

Comment: @Bernard just edited it. Hope it helps

Comment: You declare 6 columns, but use 9 column heads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some changes to the columns widths, and using the `table` environment instead of `minipage`,  seven columns will fit on the page.

The optional `\arraystretch` allows for a vertical expansion of the cells.

[image: a]

(use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}` instead of the older `\bf` for bold face)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
%\input{head}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

\usepackage{array} %<<<< added
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    
\begin{document}    
    
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \caption{Results of the regression model} 
    \label{tab:title} 
    \begin{tabular}{ C{.75in} C{.55in} *5{C{.55in}}} % changed <<<<<
        \toprule%[1.5pt]
    \bfseries Parameters & \bfseries IV C & \bfseries Standard error (SE)& \bfseries 2SLS & \bfseries Standard error (SE) &\bfseries GMM & \bfseries Standard error (SE) \\
        \bottomrule
        Cons & $2.266$ & $1.000$ & $4.087$ & $0.158$ & $4.094$ & $0.223$\\
        \midrule
        Educ & $0.223$ & $0.058$ & $0.118$ & $0.009$ & $0.117$ & $0.013$\\
        \midrule
        Exper & $0.151$ & $0.027$ & $0.105$ & $0.007$ & $0.105$ & $0.010$\\
        \midrule
        $\text{Exper}^2$ & $-0.003$ & $0.001$ & $-0.003$ & $0.000$ & $-0.003$ & $0.000$\\
        \midrule
        $South$ & $-0.086$ & $0.029$ & $-0.123$ & $0.013$ & $-0.123$ & $0.018$\\
        \midrule
        $Black$ & $-0.036$ & $0.056$ & $-0.127$ & $0.019$ & $-0.129$ & $0.026$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
        
\end{document}
```

With another flavor, using only the package `nicematrix` to build the table and adding `siunitx` to align the decimal points,
(compile twice the first time) the code is much cleaner.

The command `\Block{}` allows the use of `\\` inside.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx} % align the decimal points 

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Results of the regression model} \medskip
\label{tab:title} 
    \begin{NiceTabular}[c]{l *6{S[table-format = 1.3]} }[hlines, cell-space-limits=6pt] % horizontal lines and cell expands 
        \bfseries Parameters & \bfseries IV C & \Block{}<\bfseries>{Standard \\error \\(SE)}& \bfseries 2SLS &  \Block{}<\bfseries>{Standard \\error \\(SE)} &\bfseries GMM &  \Block{}<\bfseries>{Standard \\error \\(SE)} \\
        Cons                        & 2.266 & 1.000 & 4.087 & 0.158 & 4.094  &  0.223\\
        Educ                        & 0.223 & 0.058 & 0.118 & 0.009 & 0.117  & 0.013\\
        Exper                       & 0.151 & 0.027 & 0.105 & 0.007 & 0.105  & 0.010\\
        Exper\textsuperscript{2}    & -0.003& 0.001 & -0.003& 0.000 & -0.003 & 0.000\\
        South                       & -0.086& 0.029 & -0.123& 0.013 & -0.123 & 0.018\\
        Black                       & -0.036& 0.056 & -0.127& 0.019 & -0.129 & 0.026\\  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
            
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about one of the following two redesigns?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Results of the regression model} 
\label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]S[table-format=1.3]}}
\toprule
\thead{Parameters} 
  & {\thead{IV C}} & {\thead{Standard\\ error\\ (SE)}}
  & {\thead{2SLS}} & {\thead{Standard\\ error\\ (SE)}} 
  & {\thead{2SLS}} & {\thead{Standard\\ error\\(SE)}} 
  & {\thead{GMM}} & {\thead{Standard\\ error\\ (SE)}}\\
\midrule
Cons & 2.266 & 1.000 & 4.087 & 0.158 & 4.094 & 0.223\\
Educ & 0.223 & 0.058 & 0.118 & 0.009 & 0.117 & 0.013\\
Exper & 0.151 & 0.027 & 0.105 & 0.007 & 0.105 & 0.010\\
Exper\textsuperscript{2} & -0.003 & 0.001 & -0.003 & 0.000 & -0.003 & 0.000\\
South & -0.086 & 0.029 & -0.123 & 0.013 & -0.123 & 0.018\\
Black & -0.036 & 0.056 & -0.127 & 0.019 & -0.129 & 0.026\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\caption{Results of the regression model} 
\label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3(4)]}}
\toprule
\thead{Parameters}  & {\thead{IV C}}  & {\thead{2SLS}}  & {\thead{2SLS}}  & {\thead{GMM}} \\
\midrule
Cons                     & 2.266(1000) & 4.087(158) & 4.094(223) & 0.000(0)  \\
Educ                     & 0.223(58)   & 0.118(9)   & 0.117(13)   \\
Exper                    & 0.151(27)   & 0.105(7)   & 0.105(10)   \\
Exper\textsuperscript{2} & -0.003(1)   & -0.003(0)  & -0.003(0)   \\
South                    & -0.086(29)  & -0.123(13) & -0.123(18)  \\
Black                    & -0.036(56)  & -0.127(19) & -0.129(26)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```